# Comparing groups within the same experiment

Tags: analysis, statistics, descriptive-statistics

[image]
I've performed an experiment wherein I have stimulated cells (cell line) with a drug across different time-points - in its unmodified (Drug) or modified form (H-Drug or M-Drug).

All cells are seeded at the same concentration and all are harvested for analysis on the same day.

Method:
[image]

Cells were seeded on the same day. Cells were stimulated at 3:00 on a Wednesday (24 hour timepoint). Cells were then stimulated at 09:00 am on Thursday (6 hour timepoint) followed by 12:00 pm Thursday (3 hour timepoint) and so on until 3:00 pm on Thursday - at this time *ALL* cells were harvested and put into separate tubes according to what they were stimulated with and when e.g. 3 hour M-drug.

All tubes were analysed in sequence to measure the percentage of cells in that test tube that stained positive for that drug (i.e. as a means of measuring drug uptake)

**Question**:
I have measured the percentage uptake of a drug at different time-points (0.5 - 24 hours) for the three drug variants. **% uptake is taken as the % of cells that stain positive for that drug**

What would the correct stat test be? Would a 3-way ANOVA make sense?

Comment: @BruceET Thanks. I have since changed the experimental design. I hope I've made it clearer to understand but am still confused about the best stat test to use!

Comment: OK, getting closer. For the unmodified drug: how many subjects were averaged to get 57? Are these the same subjects averaged to get 67 half an hour later? Then different subjects for H and M? Or same subjects on a different day? And do you have data for individual subjects, or just the 15 averages shown?

Comment: @BruceET Thanks for your help. All subjects = cell lines - these are identical cells seeded at an identical density and seeded on the same day. These numbers are %,  not averages - i.e. the % of cells in each well (as shown on the diagram above) that stain positive for drug uptake.

Comment: @BruceET I've added a bit more detail to the Q - hopefully this can prove more insightful!

Comment: OK. Minitab analysis of two-factor ANOVA model shown below. From your explanation, I don't see a third factor. (Some of my now-redundant and outdated Comments now deleted.) Other analyses possible, but there is not much data and this is the simplest analysis that seems to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

According to the updated description, I see two factors:

$\delta:$ Type of drug with three levels (U, M, H), and

$\tau:$ Time period with five levels (24, 6, 3, 1, 1/2).

Data are $Y_{ij}$ percentage stained positive.

Then a standard two-way ANOVA model (without interaction) would be 
$$Y_{ij} = \mu + \delta_i + \tau_j + e_{ij},$$
for $i = 1,2,3$ and $j = 1,2,3,4;$ and $e_{ij}$ are independently
normal with mean $\mu$ and SD not depending on $i$ or $j,$
(estimated below as $\sigma = 9.8).$

Output from Minitab statistical software:

```
ANOVA: Resp versus Drg, Tim 

Factor  Type   Levels  Values
Drg     fixed       3  1, 2, 3
Tim     fixed       5  1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Analysis of Variance for Resp

Source  DF       SS      MS     F      P
Drg      2   596.93  298.47  3.14  0.099
Tim      4  2517.33  629.33  6.62  0.012
Error    8   761.07   95.13
Total   14  3875.33

S = 9.75363   R-Sq = 80.36%   R-Sq(adj) = 65.63%

Means

Drg  N    Resp
1    5  75.400
2    5  82.000
3    5  66.600

Tim  N    Resp
1    3  52.000
2    3  71.333
3    3  76.667
4    3  83.333
5    3  90.000
```

Time effect is significant at the 5% level (P-values < 0.05); Drug effect
not significant.
There is no 'Interaction' term in the model because we have
only one percentage (Y-value) for each combination of Drug and Time.
The data are sufficiently near normal because a points on a normal
probability plot of the residuals (indicators of errors in the 15
'cells' of the data table) lie very nearly in a straight line.

[image]

The Fisher LSD ('least significant difference') method of comparing
levels within Time factor is shown below:

```
Fisher Pairwise Comparisons: Response = Resp, Term = Tim 

Grouping Information Using Fisher LSD Method and 95% Confidence

Tim  N     Mean  Grouping
5    3  90.0000  A
4    3  83.3333  A   B
3    3  76.6667  A   B
2    3  71.3333      B
1    3  52.0000         C

Means that do not share a letter are significantly different.
```

That is, there is a clear trend of difference due to time.
Specifically, Level 1 (.5hr) is significantly smaller than the others;
Level 5 (24hr) is significantly larger than Level 2 (1hr) or 1.

*Note:* The Tukey HSD method of multiple comparisons shows fewer
significant differences. It is 'more conservative' (less likely to
declare significant differences). However, I believe the Fisher LSD
method is appropriate for this experiment.

Comment: Thanks @BruceET for your help. I performed a two-way ANOVA using a multiple comparisons test by comparing each column within each row (I had n =2 independent experiments). What would be the advantage of using the Fisher LSD given that it seems to exaggerate the difference?

Comment: If you have equal sample sizes for all time-by-drug 'cells' in your data table, you can do Tukey multiple comparisons. Should do Tukey if you are making a lot of comparisons. As I recall, I did Fisher here because it seemed obvious which few comparisons are of interest. // Just noticed **_I was wrong_** about P-val < 5% for drug, so diff btw Drugs 2 and 3 may not be real. Should not do any kind of multiple comparisons for levels within a non-significant main effect. _Edited Answer accordingly._